# Apply function to different columns per row depending on conditions

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying for a couple of days to create a code that lets me get the column name of the minimum of 5 columns per row. But I dont want that minimum to be the the same as two other columns values in the same row. I just can't get to work it out. I'm desperate. Please HELP!

I keep getting errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.